# cmis: getHttpInvoker() method returns DefaultHttpInvoker object

Tags: java, cmis, opencmis

I implemented custom Http invocker by extending the class DefaultHttpInvoker. After that I created session using my custom invocker implementation.

```
sessionParams.put(SessionParameter.HTTP_INVOKER_CLASS, CustomInvokerImplementation.class.getName());
```

When I query for some data using the session, it is calling DefaultHttpInvoker post method.

ItemIterable queryResults = session.query("MyQuery", false, session.getDefaultContext());

I did some analysis on this. Finally my request end up in calling post method of 'org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.browser.AbstractBrowserBindingService.java'

```
protected Response post(UrlBuilder url, String contentType, Output writer) {
        // make the call
        Response resp = getHttpInvoker().invokePOST(url, contentType, writer, session);

        // check response code
        if (resp.getResponseCode() != 200 && resp.getResponseCode() != 201) {
            throw convertStatusCode(resp.getResponseCode(), resp.getResponseMessage(), resp.getErrorContent(), null);
        }

        return resp;
    }



getHttpInvoker method imeplemented like below.
    protected HttpInvoker getHttpInvoker() {
        return CmisBindingsHelper.getHttpInvoker(session);
    }
```

From the following code, I understood that, HttpInvocker is created by using 'HTTP_INVOKER_OBJECT', if it is unable to get the HttpInvocker object using 'HTTP_INVOKER_OBJECT',
it is trying with 'SessionParameter.HTTP_INVOKER_CLASS'.

```
   public static HttpInvoker getHttpInvoker(BindingSession session) {
        assert session != null;

        HttpInvoker invoker = (HttpInvoker) session.get(HTTP_INVOKER_OBJECT);

        if (invoker != null) {
            return invoker;
        }

        session.writeLock();
        try {
            // try again
            invoker = (HttpInvoker) session.get(HTTP_INVOKER_OBJECT);
            if (invoker != null) {
                return invoker;
            }

            // ok, we have to create it...
            try {
                String invokerName = (String) session.get(SessionParameter.HTTP_INVOKER_CLASS);
                invoker = (HttpInvoker) ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(invokerName).newInstance();
            } catch (CmisBaseException e) {
                throw e;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new CmisRuntimeException("HTTP invoker cannot be initialized: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            // we have an Invoker object -> put it into the session
            session.put(HTTP_INVOKER_OBJECT, invoker, true);
        } finally {
            session.writeUnlock();
        }

        assert invoker != null;

        return invoker;
    }
```

Is there any way, I should make this to call my custom HttpInvocker implementation.

Comment: Does `session.getSessionParameters()` contain the right HttpInvoker class?

Comment: Hi Florian, getSessionParameters pointing to 'DefaultHttpInvoker'.

Comment: property 'org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.binding.httpinvoker.classname' has the value 'org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.http.DefaultHttpInvoker'

Comment: Then check your session setup. It looks like the HttpInvoker session parameter isn't set for some reason and therefore the default value is used.

Comment: Hi Florian, Thanks for the reply. I observed when my session is active (I mean valid), it is pointing to my CustomHttpInvocker, but when my session is expired, it is pointing to DefaultHttpInvoker. Is there any thing that I can do here?

Comment: What do you mean by "expired"? OpenCMIS sessions do not expire.